# About the electromagnetic wave - Could it possible for light to be bent?

Tags: waves

I saw a diagram of electromagnetic waves' running through by inter-induction between fluctuating magnetic and electric field. Then I got serious about 'If the light is, could it possible that a strong permanent magnet could intertere the route of the light?' I'm almost beginner of the physics(i have knowledges of basic electronics, literally so basic that even I haven't completely grasped the Maxwell's equation, but know a little mathematical symbols like differential & integration, transcendental functions except matrix and implicit functions) so it would be grateful if you consider my level when answering.

Answer (score 1):

No, due to:

1. The principle of superposition
2. The fact that a light wave is characterized by the **frequency** of oscillations of the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields.

The light wave will move through the magnetic field unaffected, and the total magnitude of the magnetic field through that region will be the sum of the static magnetic field you imposed and the fluctuations due to the light wave.

Comment: That means magnetic filed act as a kind of 'wave'? But i heard the 'magnetic pulse' . Waves and pulses are the different things. So is it impossible to interfere with each other, between the electromagnetic wave and magnetic field?

Comment: The closest way to think of it is the magnetic field is the "medium" through which the "wave" travels, similar to how water is the medium through which an ocean wave travels. But one wave traveling east can intersect a wave traveling south, then continue on like nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can bend light by shining it along a gradient in light speed. As with a car or tank, if the speed is higher on the left, it will turn right and vice versa.

One practical example for that are glass fibers for data links which are manufactured such that the speed of light is a bit lower towards the center: Bending the light towards the center causes less losses and distortion than having the light reflect on the edge of the glass fiber.

You will achieve the same effect by varying air density (see sparkling stars).

I will leave it to someone else to go into how to this works with $\epsilon\mu$ changing, how that changes the speed of light and how that is affected by a change in materials. (It has been 20 years since I last dealt with this subject.)

Comment: You mean the refraction index, right? 'The light slows in the microscopic scale when going through the dense medium.'

Comment: The refraction index is just another way of describing the change in speed of light.